# xpath attribute with a special character

Tags: xpath, expression, special-characters

```
$xpath->query('/html[boolean(string(normalize-space(@xml:lang))) = "true"]')
```

Normally the above query would work but in this case the xhtml attribute xml:lang has colon in it. Replacing it with entity &59; doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show us an abbreviated sample of your XML.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
</html>

Comment: This is perl, I assume. Which xml library?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a full answer but...

The important thing to note is that the attribute xml:lang doesn't have a colon in it. The attribute 'lang' is the 'xml' namespace which is not quite the same thing. The xml namespace is (in some ways) 'built-in'.

Secondly, I think you probably mean:

```
'/html[boolean(string(normalize-space(@xml:lang))) = true()]'
```

as truth and falsehood are not strings in xpath.

Now, I've run the following script in perl, using XML::LibXML and it works just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $xml = $parser->parse_file('test.html');

my ($node) = $xml->findnodes('/html[boolean(string(normalize-space(@xml:lang))) = true()]');


print $node->textContent, "\n";
```

using this as my input:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<html xml:lang='en-uk'>
        <head><title>boo</title></head>
        <body><p>boo</p></body>
</html>
```

That prints out the expected output ("`boo\nboo`").

I wonder if you are using a parser that isn't fully namespace aware. Also, what do you mean by 'works'? Are you trying to find out if an html element has an xml:lang attribute?

If you are, this would probably be a better statement:

```
'/html[@xml:lang]'
```

Comment: yep thats exactly what I mean. I'm using PHPs domxpath so I'm surprised your query works and mine doesn't. Maybe its a bug in php's library???